# How to detect multiple spaces inside code and not at the beginning of line

Tags: python-3.x, regex, atom-editor

I try to refactor python code written by someone else. QA does not want tabs, hence I replaced them by four whitespaces, but there were also a lot of tabs used inside the code, and not only for indentation at beginnings of lines.

Here is a sample piece of code:

```
    def    post(self,     request,     format=None):
        action     =     request.query_params.get('action',     None)
        res     =     'UNKNOWN ACTION'
        hhtpstatus = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

I tried these regex:

```
[^\S]([ ]{2,})[^\S]
```

This one selects correctly the multiple spaces inside the code, but select also the ones used for indentation, which I don't want. If I use this one, I'll loose the indentations...

```
[^\s]([ ]{2,})[^\S]
```

This one is better, as it only selects the multiple spaces inside the code, but takes the last character of the preceding code, which obviously I don't want neither. If I use this, I ruin all the code by scraping the last character with the multiple space following it...

I work in Atom, and the regex should detect only the multiple whitespaces encompassed by code before and code after, and select only the spaces, so I can replace them by single space

I also tried with `[^\W]` and `[^\w]` with less success: small capital still detects indentation spaces, and select all the non words code characters (, : = and so on). Big capital selects only spaces following words, not spaces following other code characters, and selects also the last word character before multiple space...

Is there so a way to use `[^\s]([ ]{2,})[^\S]`, which detects properly only the multiple spaces inside the code, but modify it to contain/select ONLY spaces, and not last preceding code character? So begin selection one character later, if this makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `[^\s]` to `\S` and change `[^\S]` to `\s` and assert them instead using lookarounds.

If you match 1 or more spaces, and assert a single space to the right, you will keep 1 space when replacing with an empty string.

```
(?<=\S)[ ]+(?=\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fcUsYi/1)

If you don't want to match the spaces at the end when there is no whitespace character following, you can match 2 or more spaces and assert a non whitspace char to the right.

Then in the replacement you can use a single space.

```
(?<=\S)[ ]{2,}(?=\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XiydRD/1)

Comment: Hi, right. It's working in regex demo but not in Atom, where somehow it works only in the imports and comments but not inside the code. I'll treat the code by copy pasting it in regex101 page. Thanks!